# Function that accepts both lvalue and rvalue arguments

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lvalue, rvalue

Is there a way to write a function in C++ that accepts both lvalue and rvalue arguments, without making it a template?

For example, suppose I write a function `print_stream` that reads from an `istream` and prints the data that was read to the screen, or something.

I think it's reasonable to call `print_stream` like this:

```
fstream file{"filename"};
print_stream(file);
```

as well as like this:

```
print_stream(fstream{"filename"});
```

But how do I declare `print_stream` so that both uses work?

If I declare it as

```
void print_stream(istream& is);
```

then the second use won't compile because an rvalue will not bind to a non-const lvalue reference.

If I declare it as

```
void print_stream(istream&& is);
```

then the first use won't compile because an lvalue will not bind to an rvalue reference.

If I declare it as

```
void print_stream(const istream& is);
```

then the function's implementation won't compile because you can't read from a `const istream`.

I can't make the function a template and use a "universal reference", because its implementation needs to be separately compiled.

I could provide two overloads:

```
void print_stream(istream& is);
void print_stream(istream&& is);
```

and have the second call the first, but that seems like a lot of unnecessary boilerplate, and I would find it very unfortunate to have to do that every time I write a function with semantics like this.

Is there something better I can do?

Comment: You could have void print_stream(Wrapper) and move the problem to the constructor of Wrapper, which only makes sense if you want to do the same for several functions.

Comment: "every time I write a function with semantics like this"? Do you often write functions which need to take a non-const non-copyable argument, and must be callable with both a temporary and a lvalue parameter? That is a pretty specific case, and not one where I'd worry about "every time I have to write a function with semantics like this". If the parameter was copyable, you could simply pass it by value. If you didn't need to call non-const functions on it, you could pass by const reference

Comment: You could write a helper caster `template <typename T> T & stay(T && t) { return t; }` and use `stay(fstream { "filename" })`.

Comment: You could go the "universal reference" way with spezialized template instance but that's just hiding away the overload thing.

Comment: @KerrekSB: While that doesn't solve this particular problem because it changes how the user has to call the function, that's a wonderful trick that I think will come in handy in many other situations. Thanks!

Comment: Make it a template, compile separately, instantiate explicitly. Minimal boilerplate.

Answer (score 28):

There is not much of a *sane* choice other than offering two overloads or making your function a template, I would say.

If you really, *really* need an (ugly) alternative, then I guess the only (insane) thing you can do is to have your function accept a `const&`, with a pre-condition saying that you cannot pass an object of a `const`-qualified type to it (you don't want to support that anyway). The function would then be allowed to cast away the `const`ness of the reference.

But I'd personally write two overloads and define one in terms of the other, so you do duplicate the declaration, but not the definition:

```
void foo(X& x) 
{ 
    // Here goes the stuff... 
}

void foo(X&& x) { foo(x); }
```

Comment: this doesn't scale well (e.g. 3 parameters -> 8 functions needed). Is there any way around that? I'm in much the same position as the OP.

Comment: @Dave Would something like this work for your use case? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e93ea8c3b693b593

Comment: @Mysticial that's a pretty neat workaround, but unfortunately 3 years later I've entirely forgotten what I needed this for. I'll keep it in mind in case it ever comes up again though!

Comment: @Mysticial If I use `foo(str1, str2)`, it will go to inifinite loop, how do I add a restriction so this line will give a compile error?

Answer (score 10):

```
// Because of universal reference
// template function with && can catch rvalue and lvalue 
// We can use std::is_same to restrict T must be istream
// it's an alternative choice, and i think is's better than two overload functions
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, istream>::value
>::type
print(T&& t) {
  // you can get the real value type by forward
  // std::forward<T>(t)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another rather ugly alternative is to make the function a template and explicitly instantiate both versions:

```
template<typename T>
void print(T&&) { /* ... */ }

template void print<istream&>(istream&);
template void print<istream&&>(istream&&);
```

This can be compiled separately. The client code only needs the declaration of the template.

I'd personaly just stick with what Andy Prowl suggests, though.

Comment: @HighCommander4 [Works for me.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=fa0857865f55a2615158e93e8ceb5a76-3725be9f9ce62f113fc473b4ae69c419)

Comment: It's not totally ugly: it allows separating the interface from implementation - that's usually a good thing.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution that scales to any number of parameters and doesn't require the accepting function to be a template.

```
#include <utility>

template <typename Ref>
struct lvalue_or_rvalue {

    Ref &&ref;

    template <typename Arg>
    constexpr lvalue_or_rvalue(Arg &&arg) noexcept
        :   ref(std::move(arg))
    { }

    constexpr operator Ref& () const & noexcept { return ref; }
    constexpr operator Ref&& () const && noexcept { return std::move(ref); }
    constexpr Ref& operator*() const noexcept { return ref; }
    constexpr Ref* operator->() const noexcept { return &ref; }

};
```

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print_stream(lvalue_or_rvalue<istream> is) {
    cout << is->rdbuf();
}

int main() {
    ifstream file("filename");
    print_stream(file); // call with lvalue
    print_stream(ifstream("filename")); // call with rvalue
    return 0;
}
```

I prefer this solution to the others because it's idiomatic, it doesn't require writing a function template every time you want to use it, and it produces sensible compiler errors, such as…

```
    print_stream("filename"); // oops! forgot to construct an ifstream
```

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr lvalue_or_rvalue<Ref>::lvalue_or_rvalue(Arg&&) [with Arg = const char (&)[9]; Ref = std::basic_istream<char>]':
test.cpp:33:25:   required from here
test.cpp:10:23: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::basic_istream<char>&&' from expression of type 'std::remove_reference<const char (&)[9]>::type' {aka 'const char [9]'}
   10 |   : ref(std::move(arg))
      |                       ^
```

The icing on the cake is that this solution also supports the implicit application of user-defined conversion constructors and conversion operators…

```
#include <cmath>

struct IntWrapper {
    int value;
    constexpr IntWrapper(int value) noexcept : value(value) { }
};

struct DoubleWrapper {
    double value;
    constexpr DoubleWrapper(double value) noexcept : value(value) { }
};

struct LongWrapper {
    long value;
    constexpr LongWrapper(long value) noexcept : value(value) { }
    constexpr LongWrapper(const IntWrapper &iw) noexcept : value(iw.value) { }
    constexpr operator DoubleWrapper () const noexcept { return value; }
};

static void square(lvalue_or_rvalue<IntWrapper> iw) {
    iw->value *= iw->value;
}

static void cube(lvalue_or_rvalue<LongWrapper> lw) {
    lw->value *= lw->value * lw->value;
}

static void square_root(lvalue_or_rvalue<DoubleWrapper> dw) {
    dw->value = std::sqrt(dw->value);
}

void examples() {
    // implicit conversion from int to IntWrapper&& via constructor
    square(42);

    // implicit conversion from IntWrapper& to LongWrapper&& via constructor
    IntWrapper iw(42);
    cube(iw);

    // implicit conversion from IntWrapper&& to LongWrapper&& via constructor
    cube(IntWrapper(42));

    // implicit conversion from LongWrapper& to DoubleWrapper&& via operator
    LongWrapper lw(42);
    square_root(lw);

    // implicit conversion from LongWrapper&& to DoubleWrapper&& via operator
    square_root(LongWrapper(42));
}
```

Comment: This one is incredible. Thank you very much! 
One question: Why the last two functions?

Comment: @Onelio: Are you asking about `operator*` and `operator->`? Those are just accessors so you don't have to use an explicit cast to access the passed reference from within the accepting function.

Answer (score 5):

**Be bold**, embrace generic forward functions and name them well.

```
template<typename Stream>
auto stream_meh_to(Stream&& s) 
->decltype(std::forward<Stream>(s) << std::string{/*   */}){
    return std::forward<Stream>(s) << std::string{"meh\n"};}
```

Note that this will work with anything that will make sense for it to work, not only `ostream`s. That is a good thing.

If the function is called with an argument that doesn't make sense, it will simply ignore this definition.
Incidentally, this works better if indentation is set to 4 spaces. :)

---

This is the same as Cube's answer, except that I am saying that it is, when possible, more elegant to *not* check for specific types and let generic programming do its thing.

Answer (score 0):

If I expect the function to take ownership of the argument of the function, I tend to put the argument as a value, and then move it in. This is not desirable if the argument is expensive to move (e.g. std::array).

A typical example is setting an object's string member:

```
class Foo {
   private:
      std::string name;
   public:
      void set_name( std::string new_name ) { name = std::move(new_name); }
};
```

With this definition of the function, I can call set the name with no copies of the string object:

```
Foo foo;
foo.set_name( std::string("John Doe") );
// or
std::string tmp_name("Jane Doe");
foo.set_name( std::move(tmp_name) );
```

But I can create a copy it if I want to keep the ownership of the original value:

```
std::string name_to_keep("John Doe");
foo.set_name( name_to_keep );
```

This last version would have very similar behavior to passing const reference and making a copy assignment:

```
class Foo {
   // ...
   public:
      void set_name( const std::string& new_name ) { name = new_name; }
};
```

This is specially useful for constructors.

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well:

```
template<class T>
class universal_reference_wrapper : public std::reference_wrapper<T>
{
    typedef std::reference_wrapper<T> base_type;
    universal_reference_wrapper(universal_reference_wrapper const &) = delete;
public:
    constexpr universal_reference_wrapper(T &v) noexcept : base_type(v) { }
    constexpr universal_reference_wrapper(T &&v) noexcept : base_type(v) { }
    constexpr T &operator *() noexcept { return this->get(); }
    constexpr T *operator->() noexcept { return std::addressof(**this); }
};
```

Usage:

```
#include <fstream>

void foo(universal_reference_wrapper<std::fstream> f)
{
    f->close();
}

void bar()
{
    std::fstream f;
    foo(f);
    foo(std::move(f));
}
```