# Why passing rvalue reference (X&&) is AS IF passing lvalue reference (X&)?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, rvalue-reference, rvalue

While I was studying rvalue reference, I found a strange answer from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17644192/3577745).

The questioner wants to avoid code duplication between a function that receive parameter as a **lvalue reference**, and another one is a function that receive a **rvalue reference**.        Both functions do the same thing.

Here is the issue:-

```
void foo(X& x)  { /*complex thing*/       }      //#A
void foo(X&& x) { /*complex SAME thing*/  }      //#B
```

Here is the proposed solution.  It is modified a bit by me:-

```
void foo(X& x)  {  /*complex thing*/ }      //#A
void foo(X&& x) { foo(x);            }      //#B
```

### **Question**

Why doesn't my version lead to stack overflow exception?
In my version, why `foo#B` call `foo#A`, but not `foo#B`?

More specifically, which C++ rule enforces this behavior?

Comment: "what is a C++ rule that enforces this strange behavior" What do you mean by this? Do you mean which rule or set of rules define this behaviour?

Comment: @juanchopanza I mean official rule of syntax.  It is like a law of C++.  I am not sure how to call it.

Comment: Try `void foo(X&& x) { foo(std::move(x)); }`.

Comment: @Zereges No, it is a too generous way to destroy my brittle computer.

Comment: You should really provide more context *in the question*. The question you reference could for example be deleted, and then this question stops making any sense.

Comment: @hyde Agree, I have edited as you adviced.  Thank.  Feel free to edit it more if you have anything to add. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the rule of [value categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), as a named parameter, `x` is an [lvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue). Then `foo#A` will be invoked, because `x` could be bound to lvalue-reference, but not rvalue-reference.

Note that the fact that `x` is declared as an rvalue-reference has nothing to do with the value category of `x`.

> #### lvalue
>
> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> - the name of a variable or a function in scope, regardless of type, such as std::cin or std::endl. Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression;

You can use `std::move` to make it an [xvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#xvalue) (rvalue), then `foo#B` will be selected (as you expected).

Comment: Just curious, from the conversion (`X&&` -> `X&`), will there be any (potentially-expensive) object copying?  In other words, will copy constructor or copy assignment be called?

Comment: No. There's no copying involved.

Comment: @javaLover When calling `foo#A`? No, copy won't occur when passing by reference; the rule won't change.

Answer (score 5):

Although you have an answer already saying where the C++ standard specifies this, let me also answer *why* it specifies this.

The idea behind rvalue reference function parameters is that the functions may assume the referenced object, or at least its contents, will no longer be used after the function returns.

Now suppose you have

```
void f(const X&x); // doesn't modify x
void f(X&&x); // clears x's data
```

and you try

```
void g(X&&x) {
    f(x);
    std::cout << "we just called f(" << x << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

This wouldn't be useful if it called `f(X&&)`, because `x`'s contents would be gone before they could get printed.

`g` needs to explicitly tell `f` that it's okay to take over the object. `f` cannot assume that `g` won't need it again later.

It might work if the compiler could somehow figure out that `x` is no longer needed, when `g`'s body no longer refers to `x`, but that's a *very* complicated problem to solve and unless the rules spell out exactly when it should and shouldn't be done, compilers won't implement it the same way, making it very likely that code that works on one compiler breaks on the next.