# What is the proper way to declare a function that can take either rvalue or lvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I want to have a function `foo` taking either lvalue or rvalue reference as the parameter.

I could break it into two overloads taking lvalue and rvalue references.

```
void foo(int& a){/*some impl*/} // lvalue ref
void foo(int&& a){foo(a);} // rvalue ref
int main(){
  int a;
  foo(a); // lvalue
  foo(1); // rvalue
}
```

It does work but is pretty verbose. I could improve it using templates.

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T &&a) { /*some impl*/ }
int main(){
  int a;
  foo(a); // lvalue, T = int&
  foo(1); // rvalue, T = int
}
```

For a binary function the template would need to take two template parameters.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void foo(T1 &&a, T2 &&b) { /*some impl*/ }
int main(){
  int a;
  foo(a, a); // (lvalue, lvalue), T1 = int&, T2 = int&
  foo(1, 1); // (rvalue, rvalue), T1 = int,  T2 = int
  foo(1, a); // (rvalue, lvalue), T1 = int,  T2 = int&
  foo(a, 1); // (lvalue, rvalue), T1 = int&, T2 = int
}
```

Is it the way to go? Is there any better way?

I have hardly any experience using cpp but it seems suspicious that I need to do such tricks to simply say "do not make copies of passed parameters".

I am using `gcc 5.4.0` with `-std=c++11`.

-- UPDATE 1 --

I came up with the question when I was using [streams](https://github.com/jscheiny/Streams) library `range(T&& lower, T&& upper)` method which takes both `T&&` parameters. I can pass both `lvalue` or `rvalue` parameters to the function but it makes me unable to pass for example `0` and `some_var` as parameters. Whatever is the author's reasons for the function taking `T&&` parameters I was wondering if there is a way to extend the declaration to take mixed lvalue/rvalue parameters without sacrificing whatever the author wanted to achieve.

-- UPDATE 2 --

If the parameter is read-only `const &` can be used ([@RichardCritten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059346/what-is-the-proper-way-to-define-functions-that-can-take-either-rvalue-or-lvalue?noredirect=1#comment71291142_42059346)).

When you want to modify/return the parameter without copying you can use either templates or [@Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42059439/1610532) solution.

[@Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42059439/1610532) solution seems better when you declare a function that takes multiple parameters.

For example, if a function takes two int l/r-value reference parameters and returns int reference using templates leads to a messy signature.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
int& foo(T1 &&a, T2 &&b) {
  a += b;
  return a;
}
```

While [@Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42059439/1610532) solution gives a pretty elegant one.

```
int& foo(any_ref<int> a, any_ref<int> b) {
  a += b;
  return a;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the exercise? Why can't you have a function taking its parameter the old-fashioned way, by value or by const reference?

Comment: If you have no need to change the value of parameter just use `T const &`

Comment: This question is usually associated with an XY-problem  , perhaps you could describe in more detail the situation that caused you to ask about this

Comment: @IgorTandetnik @M.M I came up with this question when I was using [streams](https://github.com/jscheiny/Streams/blob/master/source/Stream.h) library `range(T&& lower, T&& upper)` method which takes both rvalue reference parameters which makes me unable to pass for example `0` and `some_var` as parameters.

Comment: @RichardCritten I guess my question makes more sense when I want to modify or return the parameter without copying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function that accepts both lvalue and rvalue arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644133/function-that-accepts-both-lvalue-and-rvalue-arguments)

Comment: The code you link to for rationale uses universal references. This is very different to what's actually in your question regarding `int&&` which is not a universal reference. `T&&` (where T is a template parameter) binds to lvalues, but `int&&` does not.  The stuff in the update should be a separate question to everything that came before (i.e. how can I modify this `range` function template to accept `(0, some_var)`)

Comment: @M.M I believe that knowing how to declare a function that can take either lvalue or rvalue reference is enough to extend the `range` function. @Yakk solution while not perfect seems to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class T>
struct any_ref{
  T& t;
  any_ref(T&in):t(in){}
  any_ref(T&&in):any_ref(in){}
  any_ref(any_ref const&)=default;
  any_ref& operator=(any_ref const&)=default;
  ~any_ref()=default;

  operator T&()const&{return t;}
  operator T&&()&&{return std::move(t);}// maybe
  T& get()const{return *this;}
};
```

Then:

```
void foo(any_ref<int>a, any_ref<int>b);
```

is not a template function.  The body can do a `int&a=a_arg;` if it wants real references.

But really, just take `int&` if you want a "maybe-out" parameter.  Callers who want to pass an rvalue as a lvalue can write:

```
templare<class T>
T& as_lvalue(T&&t){return t;}
```

and cast their rvalueness away.

If the parameter is a read only reference, use `const&`.

Comment: If only you could get rid of the `get` function. Anyway, it does everything I want it to do. I wonder why the standard does not define a proper tool to do it.

Comment: @MarcinKról because `as_lvalue` is probably a better way to do it -- mark up the rvalue as an lvalue at the call-site.  It is exceedingly rare you want to have a reference parameter that can be modified that should bind to a temporary; I've rarely seen a situation where it wouldn't have been better to have a in parameter and a distinct (ignorable) out-parameter (as part of the return value).  I've seen it, but it is rare, and in those rare cases, `as_lvalue` does fine.